# How to handle error on batch tasks in flink

Tags: scala, exception, apache-flink

In my flink job there is a specific task "GroupReduce" that involve external system (elasticsearch in this case) that can encounter an timeout exception.

A simple try and catch is not enought because i don't want to just skip the groupreduce task if an error occure.

There is a way to, once cought the exception, to inform flink for repeat just that subtask with a delay of T milliseconds?
Or something like that .

Comment: There is someone that can help me ? ;(